# Clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for some suggestions regarding clustering.
Lets say
I have 5 subjects (1, 2, 3, 4 and 5)

```
1 says  2 and 3 are similar to 1
2 says 1 is similar 2
3 says 5 is similar to 3
4 says no one is similar to 4
5 says 3 is similar to 5
```

So we have a matrix like

```
1 - 2 3,
2 - 1, 
3 - 5,
4 - 0,
5 - 3
```

I need to cluster saying

```
cluster1 - 1 and 2 
cluster2 - 4
cluster3 - 3 and 5
```

any suggestions to do clustering based on this type of data?
most clustering are based on calculating the distance difference. But here I think that is not the case.
Thank you!

Comment: You're giving a distance measure yourself in your first statement, where you propose a similarity between subjects. Then, you say you don't think there's a distance to be considered; how do you come to that conclusion? It's a bit odd and might indicate you haven't thought about the system as a whole.

Comment: instead of 1,2, 3, 4 and 5 lets say A, B, C, D and E... 
A - B and C, 
B - A,
C - E,
D - None and E- C....... now how to approach for doing cluster?? cluster1- A and B, cluster2- D and cluster3- C and E???

Comment: The names never had any meaning. I don't know, I think you're not really understanding what "distance" is in this context.

Comment: Can I please ask if this question was resolved?

Comment: Yes! I used ROCK algorithm based on estimating the Jaccard Coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really looking for a clustering algorithm in the common meaning of the word, but more of a Graph Theory concept.

> So we have a matrix like

That is not a matrix. That is an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) that states nodes adjacent to others.

The "matrix" you might be after is the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). For a simple graph (a graph that does not contain nodes with self-connections), $G(V, E)$ where $V$ is the set of vectors and $E$ is the set of edges, the adjacency matrix $A$ tells you if there is a connection between two vertices in $V$. For example, $a_{2,3}$ would tell you if there is a connection between vertices $v_2, v_3 \in V$.

Applied to your problem, the adjacency matrix looks like this:

$$V = \{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}0 1 1 0 0 \\ 1 0 0 0 0 \\ 0 0 0 0 1 \\ 0 0 0 0 0 \\ 0 0 1 0 0\end{bmatrix} $$

A single graph can be composed of [a number of components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). In your case, node 4 is completely unconnected and it could be considered as a component.

If your graph was undirected, the task of finding connected components would be [very simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms). But, your graph is directed. This is denoted by the lack of symmetry of $A$ around the main diagonal ($A_{1,3} \ne A_{3,1}$). In this case, you would be looking for [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) algorithms.

A Python module you can use to compute both is [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/). With functions for connected components and strongly connected components [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) and [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_components.html) respectively.

This concept of clustering is very interesting but (at first view) quite different than the traditional clustering of data points in some space based on "similarity". See for example [this type of clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) and you will see why you need a concept of "distance". In your type of problem, this would be equivalent to having the nodes also report **HOW SIMILAR** they are to each other. Then, in addition to direction, you would also have [a weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_matrix) (similarity) associated with each edge. In that case, things get [a little bit more complicated](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0971.pdf).

Hope this helps.